# Handle DownloadManager on click event and start system Downloads application from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

I have an application that downloads big files from http. 
To handle this, I used `DownloadManager`.

The files to download are too big and I want that the user will be able to put the application in background and use freely his phone while the download runs.

In the code that I written download starts and it works correctly, but I need that whenever the user click on the downloading file's name in the notification bar it must shows him the download list (system application Downloads - `DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS`).

What I want is that my applications will work exactly like the download manager of the default browser when the browser downloads files from web.

Can you please help me in declaring and code the `BroadcastReceiver`? As I said I need a `BroadcastReceiver` that runs always.

I tried to do this, but it doesn't work:

In my manifest there is:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <receiver android:name="com.test.BroadcastReceiverDownloadManager">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And my BroadcastReceiverDownloadManager.java is this one:

```
public class BroadcastReceiverDownloadManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.v("MY_APP","!!! onReceive !!!");

        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED.equals(action))
        {               
            Intent i = new Intent(context,DownloadManager.class);
            i.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
            context.startActivity(i);       
        }        
    }
}
```

It sometimes doesn't handle the click event, and whenever it handle the click correctly the applications crashes in this way:

```
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.my.app.name.services.BroadcastReceiverDownloadManager: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.my.app.name/android.app.DownloadManager}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2408)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.my.app.name/android.app.DownloadManager}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1634)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1510)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1100)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:276)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:276)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at com.my.app.name.services.BroadcastReceiverDownloadManager.onReceive(BroadcastReceiverDownloadManager.java:29)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2397)
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: When you say "crashes", what is the stack trace?

Comment: I added the log in my post.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the log:

```
02-27 19:13:04.098: E/AndroidRuntime(13274): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.my.app.name/android.app.DownloadManager}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

In order to launch an activity, you have to declare it. Open the file AndroidManifest.xml, and make sure inside the application tag you have declared the activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".DownloadManager"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
    </activity>
```

The ".DownloadManager" should have the same package name as the app. If you want to use a different package than the app, specify it completely, e.g.
            android:name="com.my.app.name.DownloadManager"

It looks to me like there is some confusion about package names. In the log it lists com.my.app.name for the activity. The receiver is com.my.app.name.services.BroadcastReceiverDownloadManager, but in the manifest you have com.test.BroadcastReceiverDownloadManager.

What are the package names in the actual Java files? They need to be consistent with the manifest.